# Unwanted duplicate of records when editing post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does rails create a new a post when it should edit the existing one instead?
I do have `method: :post` in my form_for which is probably why it's creating the post instead of editing it with the get method, but if I try and take that method away the whole form will stop working.

Form:

```
<div class="signin">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="well boxShadow">
            <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading red">New Question</h4>
              <hr />
              <%= form_for(@question, url: questions_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

                <% if @question.errors.any? %>
                  <div id="error_explanation">
                    <h4><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h4>

                    <ul>
                    <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                      <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <% end %>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control outline", :placeholder => "Enter your question" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "form-control outline", rows: 15 %>
                    </div>
                  </div>                

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Ask", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :questions

  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
  resources :users

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers
  end

  resources :answers
end
```

Show view:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="media-heading ques"><%= @question.title %></h3>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="well">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <br/>
                      <p><%= @question.description %></p>
                   </div>

                   <div class="pull-right">
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <% if @question.user_id == current_user.id %>
                            <%= link_to 'edit', edit_question_path(@question), :class => "text-muted links" %>
                            <%= link_to 'delete', question_path(@question), :method => :delete, :class => "text-muted links" %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>               
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>

    <!-- About the auther -->

              <div class="well">
                  <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left">
                    <% if @question.user.avatar.blank? %>
                        <img src="http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png" style="width: 75px;">
                    <% elsif @question.user.avatar %>
                        <%= image_tag @question.user.avatar, :style => "width:75px;" %>
                    <% end %>
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <p>About <%= link_to @question.user.username, @question.user, :class => " bg" %></p>
                   </div>
                   <p class="text-muted small">Apparently this user doesn't like to share his information.</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Answers -->
              <div class="well">
                  <div class="media">
                  <h4 class="media-heading red">Answers</h4>
                  <hr>
                      <%= render :partial => @question.answers %>
                </div>
              </div>

            <!-- Answer form -->
            <div class="well boxShadow">
                <div class="media">
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading red">Answer</h4>
                  <hr />
                  <%= form_for [@question, Answer.new], :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "form-control outline", rows: 15 %>
                        </div>
                      </div>                
                      <br/><br/>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <%= f.submit "Answer", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block mar20" %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <% end %>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="blogC">
                <br>
                    <p><span style="padding-right: 10px;" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> asked <%= time_ago_in_words(@question.created_at) %> ago </span></p>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="blogC">
                    <h4 class="red">Recent Blogs</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Test blog 123 123</a></p>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="blogC">
                    <h4 class="red">Sponsors</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <img src="http://webneel.com/daily/sites/default/files/images/daily/03-2013/4-animal-rights-sweden-boxer-animal-ad.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Questions controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@questions)
  end

  def show
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      @question = current_user.questions.build
      respond_with(@question)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
    if @question.save
      redirect_to question_path(@question)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @question.update(question_params)
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

Full trace:

```
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Server logs:

```
Started PUT "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-26 06:23:52 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/questions"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
start_thread'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
```

Comment: Add you `questions_controller.rb` also.

Comment: @Vucko updated my question

Comment: As @Pavan said, use `put`. If you type `rake routes | grep questions`, you'll see that `questions_path` with `post` method is used to target the `questions#create` method in your controller.

Comment: @Vucko I tried it and it just gave me a no route matches put error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it by first removing the duplicate question resources from the routes:

**Updated routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
  resources :users

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers
  end

  resources :answers
end
```

Then I created a new partial for the edit view and updated this line:

**From:**

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: questions_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

**To:**

```
<%= form_for(@question, html: { method: :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `PUT` to ***update*** the record. The below should work

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: questions_path, html: { method: :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: it gave me a `No route matches [PUT] "/questions"`

Comment: @Raymond I want it from the beginning of the error line. Can you update it?

Comment: That's all what it gave me

Comment: @Raymond After the `No route matches [PUT] "/questions"` did it said any missing required keys?

Comment: It's basically now searching for `localhost:3000/questions` and no it didn't it just displayed the routes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104644/discussion-between-raymond-and-pavan).